# Exiting python causes unusual bash behaviour

Tags: python, bash, shell, exit

I changed my shell from tcsh to bash, but i observe a strange behavior when using python interactively.

When i exit python using `quit()` or `exit()` or `ctrl+D` bash starts behaving [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUHbA.png), that is everytime i hit enter with no commands no newline is added and if i try to type anything, nothing actually is written, but somehow it is recorded and when i press enter it is executed if it is recognized as a legitimate command, othewise  a `command not found` error appears, [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vcih0.png).
Using a `reset` on the shell brings everything back to normal. New shells behave normally.

I really don't know what could be causing this, can someone please help me?

PS: please ask if it is not clear enough.

EDIT - Result of `env`:

```
TERM_PROGRAM=Apple_Terminal
SHELL=/bin/bash
TERM=xterm-256color
TMPDIR=/var/folders/6s/ff31kwgj13s7ftrr_jdy06tc0000gq/T/
Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.rPKPaf8CHZ/Render
TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION=361.1
TERM_SESSION_ID=3973FE8A-ABFF-455D-8278-E43CFC75A7D3
USER=mazzalex02
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.ZBZiVF7Brq/Listeners
__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING=0x1F7:0x0:0x4
PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/opt/local/lib/pgsql/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin
PWD=/Users/mazzalex02
DBUS_LAUNCHD_SESSION_BUS_SOCKET=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.HDW6moBcXw/unix_domain_listener
LANG=it_IT.UTF-8
XPC_FLAGS=0x0
XPC_SERVICE_NAME=0
SHLVL=1
HOME=/Users/mazzalex02
LOGNAME=mazzalex02
DISPLAY=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.sgSgWxHdhI/org.macports:0
_=/usr/bin/env
OLDPWD=/Users/mazzalex02
```

EDIT2 - This does not happen using python in `/usr/bin/`

Comment: This is a misconfiguration of either your shell or you defined `python` as an alias that does more work than just start Python. It is not a problem that Python itself can cause however.

Comment: Ok, so what can i do? How can i find what i did wrong?

Comment: On the bash prompt, what does `type python` produce? What is the output of `env`?

Comment: Result of `type python` is `python is hashed (/opt/local/bin/python)`

Comment: So no alias or function definition. That leaves your bash configuration. Perhaps this is better suited to the Linux / Unix SE as this is a bash configuration issue, not a programming issue.

Comment: I'll try there if nothing comes up here, thanks.

Comment: Just for verification, does this also happen with `/usr/bin/python`? You have a custom Python in `/opt/local/`, I'm thinking it could be a readline library issue (though I doubt it, but better to have checked).

Comment: Ah, see [Using python screws up the shell (and/or terminal?)!](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/206795) This is an issue with the readline library you compiled against.

Comment: How did you install the `/opt/local/bin/python`?

Comment: Using macports, should i try to uninstall and reinstall?

Comment: @MartijnPieters, i'll read it now

Comment: @MartijnPieters i'll install it now

Comment: Since you are using macports, this is definitely an Apple-specific problem. I'd migrate you to Ask Different but all that'll happen there is that the question is closed as a duplicate of the one I linked you to.

Comment: @MartijnPieters that question gave the right answer! I installed py27-readline and now everything works!